# what am I going to do with this Facebook alert? about the permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions

**OAuth Dialog Read and Write Permissions**
Your app appears to be requesting both read and write permissions at the same time. Instead, request a small number of permissions initially, and ask for write permissions when the user decides to share.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it is a mistake from Facebook developpers.

Someone has [asked the same question here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers), and a facebook engineer answered:

> The alert went out by mistake and we are working on cleaning it up. You can ignore it.

Comment: Static link: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/534303256613193/

Comment: I don't think it's a mistake. This will be mandatory in the next few months : _Facebook will separately ask if you want the app to post on your behalf and to whom._ source : http://www.facebook.com/about/login/

Answer (score 2):

You should not ask `publish_stream`, `publish_actions` or any other write permission when user register to  App. These permission should be asked separately when required.

As per Facebook Engineer "You can just ignore it for now. But it is good to ask for read permissions when someone start using your app. And then only ask for write permissions when it is actually needed"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permission like read_stream,publish_stream etc..

Check it out : http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-ask-for-extended-permission-in-your-facebook-application/32/

Comment: Isn't it asking me not to set the read and write permission together?

Comment: Thank you but not this problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think there was a problem with the developers alert system so you can see both "fix now" and "resolved" buttons at the same time. But I think the alert message is real and its not pushed by mistake.  Facebook wants to encourage you to reduce the number of permissions you ask for initially; especially when the user is logging into your application for the first time.  Then later you can ask for other permissions when you need them.

This is just good practice in following the security guideline of [Least Privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) - request/allow only the minimum required permissions for a user to accomplish the tasks that they need to do.  Doing so minimizes the vulnerability of your application.

So I think if you ask just for the most necessary permissions at the first time login and do not mix permission types (read and write) in the same request this will solve your problem.