# OAuth Dialog Read/Write Permissions in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Yesterday I received in one of my Facebook apps this message:

[image]

Tried to look for documentation about it but couldn't find it. What does it mean? I can't request READ/WRITE permissions anymore? I must do it sepparately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone cited out in other question, it looks like it is not your fault and you cannot do anything about it.

---

Quoted from **Fabrice Lefloch** in [what am I going to do with this Facebook alert? about the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052157/what-am-i-going-to-do-with-this-facebook-alert-about-the-permissions)

---

It seems that it is a mistake from Facebook developpers.

Someone has asked the same question here, and a facebook engineer answered:

```
The alert went out by mistake and we are working on cleaning it up. You can ignore it.
```

Comment: Static Link: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/534303256613193/